# asp.net web forms apps disallowing multi-user session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

My asp.net 4.5 web forms app is disallowing multiple session or session timeout or something. The first one or two person login successfully and use the system until a third or more person tries login and it redirects them to the login page. Hitting F12 I get the following message

> Password fields present in a form with an insecure (http://) form
>   action. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to
>   be stolen

Here is my login button code:

```
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_db);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
        ApplicationUser user = userManager.Find(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (user.IsDeleted && user.UserName.ToLower() != ApplicationDbInitializer.userName.ToLower())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Your account has been deleted.");

            }
            else if (!user.IsActive && user.UserName.ToLower() != ApplicationDbInitializer.userName.ToLower())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Your account has been disabled.");
            }
            else
            {
                IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
                authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
                ClaimsIdentity identity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                AuthenticationProperties props = new AuthenticationProperties();
                props.IsPersistent = chkRememberMe.Checked;
                authenticationManager.SignIn(props, identity);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
                {
                    Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
                }
                else if (userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin"))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/admin/index");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/user/index");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<sessionState timeout="2880"></sessionState>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<compilation targetFramework="4.5">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Try out with this. Hopefully it works.

```
    <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="2880" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: hi i do I also include:     <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>   am only including <sessionState cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="2880" /> in my web.config file
    </httpModules>

Comment: yup. include even `httpModules`.

Comment: as you said that the application allows login for 2 users. But if more than two users login, than does the session ends for all the users? or does the session end only for the extra users except the first 2 users?

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying the site via HTTPS? If so, I think your login `<form>` tag has a hard-coded Yeo in it that points to a non-secure HTTP url. Update the tag to contain a relative path, and don't encode the protocol in your HTML.

Comment: Am not deploying via https. Where in the code is the tag hard-coded Yeo you mentioned? Can you provide more infor please???

Comment: In aspx pages, I think you're looking for a tag like `<form runat="server">`. Normally on a master page. It's been a long time, though, so I could be remembering wrong.